# JSON to Swift dictionary

Tags: json, swift, dictionary

Hello I have this JSON object and I want to make a dictionary from it.

```
 {
availableHours :{ 
    "Monday" : [ ["5:30","11:00"] , ["13:00","16:00"] ],
    "Tuesday" : [ ["14:30","19:50"] ],
    "Friday" : [ ["7:30","12:50"], ["16:00","23:59"] ]
    }
}
```

I want it to be:

```
available_hours =  [ 
    "Monday" : [ ["5:30","11:00"] , ["13:00","16:00"] ],
    "Tuesday" : [ ["14:30","19:50"] ],
    "Friday" : [ ["7:30","12:50"], ["16:00","23:59"] ]
 ]
```

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: That's not JSON.. in any case, search for "parse JSON in Swift". There be answers aplenty.

Comment: I want to get availableHours as a swift dictionary

Answer (score 1):

```
let available_hours : [String : [[String]]] = NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(availableHours, options: NSJSONReadingOptions.AllowFragments, error:&parseError) as [String : [[String]]]
```

Maybe this post helps: http://www.raywenderlich.com/82706/working-with-json-in-swift-tutorial